# Angular2 beta getting exception "No provider for Router! (RouterLink -> Router)"

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I have been banging my head against this for two days now.  I am trying to implement some simple routing in Angular2 beta0.0.2.  Please note that I am using **typescript**.

So what I understand is that I need to bootstrap my root app component with **ROUTER_PROVIDERS** so that these services are available to my who app **AND** set the directives for the components that want to implement routing to **ROUTER_DIRECTIVES**.

Here is what I have:

```
//ANGULAR  ******************************
import {provide, Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {
        APP_BASE_HREF,
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HashLocationStrategy,
        LocationStrategy,
        RouteConfig,
        } from 'angular2/router';

//COMPONENTS  ******************************
import {ShiftCalendarComponent} from './components/calendar/shift-calendar.component';
import {ShiftAdminComponent} from './components/admin/shift-admin.component';
import {ShiftListComponent} from './components/shifts/shift-list.component';

//CLASS  ******************************
@Component({
    selector: 'shift-app',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `<div>
                 <nav>
                     <h3> Navigation: </h3>
                     <ul>
                         <li><a [routerLink]="['Calendar']" > Home </a></li>
                         <li><a [routerLink]="['Admin']" > About </a></li>
                         <li><a [routerLink]="['Shifts']" > Contact us </a></li>
                     </ul>
                 </nav>            
                 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
             </div>`
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', name: 'root', redirectTo: ['/Calendar'] },
    { path: '/calendar', name: 'Calendar', component: ShiftCalendarComponent },
    { path: '/admin', name: 'Admin', component: ShiftAdminComponent },
    { path: '/shifts', name: 'Shifts', component: ShiftListComponent }
])
export class ShiftApp { } 

//BOOTSTRAP   ******************************
    bootstrap(ShiftApp, [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
        provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),
        provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '/' })    
    ]);
```

The angular app loads and the template is displayed, but no link works and I get the following error in my console:

> EXCEPTION: No provider for Router! (RouterLink -> Router) angular2.dev.js

In my index.html (which i call view.html) I have linked to all the relevant libraries and have included **router.dev.js** and the sources tab of my console shows me that all the needed scripts are successfully loaded.

I have read about every stack overflow question with router link errors for Angular2 and the entire router docs but cannot find why mine is not working.  As far as I can tell my code matches [the Angular2 Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

[This documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/ROUTER_DIRECTIVES-let.html) shows that the ROUTER_DIRECTIVES includes the  directives like RouterOutlet and RouterLink

### Question?

If I am successfully setting the directives for the component to **ROUTER_DIRECTIVES**, why am I getting the "No provider for Router! RouterLink" error?

Comment: There must be something else in the application that's not in the post, I recreated the code your provided and it works on my end. You can download my code from here, maybe you spot the difference which makes it work on my end: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwb6Bsfrx94pX0RzdXl0VlNmdWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks, ill take a look right now

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi - Dude! Digital High Five - I moved my code around to match yours and it works.  I was applying the bootstrapping to a child component and not the main root component.  If you post an answer with the code from your boot.ts file I will accept it.  Thanks Again!

Comment: I'm happy it got sorted out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your bootstrapping process into s separate file:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {provide, Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ShiftApp} from './app.component';

import {
    APP_BASE_HREF,
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HashLocationStrategy,
    LocationStrategy
} from 'angular2/router';

bootstrap(ShiftApp, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),
    provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '/' })
]);
```

Import that new file in your index.html:

```
System.config({
    packages: {
        app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
System.import('app/boot')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Advantages of doing that can be found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#main).

Also as mentioned in the comment, bootstrap your root component instead of a child component.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is injecting to boot.ts (bootloader file)

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

i am  having issue "EXCEPTION: No provider for Router! (RouterLink -> Router)" and i have success fully fix it by making changes in boot.ts, Configure your boot.ts according to below code and it will work fine.

```
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';


bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),
  HTTP_PROVIDERS
]);
```